# selecting different classes on number

Tags: php

I have a website which has some kind of guestbook, people can write their comments about my website there, this is my current code to define which css class the post must be:

(ive set postnum to 12 for now because this would normaly be returned from the database.

```
<?php
$postnum = 12

for($post =0; $post < $postnum; $postnum = $postnum++){
    echo"<div class='greendiv'> //post stuff here </div>";
    $postnum++;
    echo"<div class='reddiv'> //post stuff here </div>";
    $postnum++;
    echo"<div class='bluediv'> //post stuff here </div>";      
}

?>
```

but in my opinion this is a bad solution, are there better practices to do this?

Comment: why you increasing $postnum 3 times

Comment: because i have 3 classes for posts, the green, red and blue one

Comment: you need all div 12 times?

Comment: no, I need green for one post, then red and then blue, then repeat this until I got 12 posts in total.

Comment: if you need all one time why you using loop?

Comment: to loop trough all the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cycle through the different classes, why not use an array?

```
<?php
$postnum = 12;

// define which classes are available
$postClasses = array('greendiv', 'reddiv', 'bluediv');

for ($post = 0; $post < $postnum; $post++) {
    // use modulo to select class
    $postClass = $postClasses[$post % count($postClasses)];

    // print some HTML
    echo '<div class="'. $postClass . '">post stuff here</div>';
}
```

Comment: This looks like a more solid way of handling, Thanks!